# Customize legend and color scale in interactive charts `altair`

Tags: python, altair

I want an interactive chart, so I first define

```
click = selection_multi(fields=['species'])
```

Inside the `encode()` method the following works well:

```
color = condition(click, 
                  'species',
                  value('gray'))
```

But I'd rather use my own color `palette` and I do not want a `legend`. I can achieve this with the following.

```
color = Color('species',
              scale=Scale(range=palette),
              legend=None)
```

But now I have no selection! Can I have them both?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get a multi-selection, your own palette and no legend, simply specify all of these inside `color().`

**Working Code**

```
import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data
iris = data.iris()

click = alt.selection_multi(fields=['species'])
palette = alt.Scale(domain=['setosa', 'versicolor', 'virginica'],
                  range=['lightgreen', 'darkgreen', 'olive'])

alt.Chart(iris).mark_point().encode(
    x='petalWidth',
    y='petalLength',    
    color=alt.condition(click,
                        'species:N', alt.value('lightgray'), 
                        scale=palette,
                        legend=None)
).properties(
    selection=click
)
```

produces:

[image]

And if you click on any point, that whole species will get selected and colored according to the color condition. (Selected points assume color from the `palette` and the unselected ones are shown in grey.)

Comment: Thank you @Ram. The class `Color` has the attribute `condition`.  Do you know if this can be used to control the selection ?  (One solution is sufficient though - just curious)